# php session_start options parameter

Tags: php

I need to start a simple php session and make it last for one day, I tried this: `session_start(['cookie_lifetime' => 86400,]);` as the manual indicates, but adobe Dreamweaver says there is a syntax error in the code.

Any help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would like to know why I always get a votedown, what are the rules? why not vote down and explain why

Answer (score 2):

You have extra comma in code

```
session_start(['cookie_lifetime' => 86400,]);
```

to

```
session_start(['cookie_lifetime' => 86400]);
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought and tried, but still I got the same syntax error in dreamweaver